# How to ignore lines containing curly braces when using the Tabular plugin in Vim?

Tags: regex, vim, vim-tabular

Consider aligning properties in a CSS file using the [Tabular plugin](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) in Vim. Suppose we have the following CSS ruleset:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;  
  font-family: arial, verdana;
}
```

With the cursor inside the rule, `vi{` followed by `:Tab /:\zs` results in

```
body {
  margin:      0;
  padding:     0;  
  font-family: arial, verdana;
}
```

However, I would like to align all the property values in *all* rulesets in the file at once, not just in one ruleset.

Running the same Tabular command for all lines (`:%Tab /:\zs`) does achieve the desired effect, as rule names needlessly affect the width of the left column. Besides, some CSS rules contain several `:` characters.

How to ignore lines containing curly braces when running such Tabular command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To work around the issue, one can eliminate the problematic lines from
affecting the width of the first column by prepending the column
separator at the start of each of those lines. When the alignment is
done, this extra prefix can be easily removed. Following this approach
we will have three commands, like so:

```
:%g/:.*{/ s/^/:/ | exe '%Tab/^[^:]*:\zs' | %s/^:\s*//
```

You can map this command to a shortcut, or even run it automatically
when a CSS file is saved:

```
:autocmd BufWrite *.css %g/:.*{/ s/^/:/ | exe '%Tab/^[^:]*:\zs' | %s/^:\s*//
```

Comment: @Eric: I've changed the heuristics to neutralize the issue with selectors.  Note that this could affect comments containing colon (more truly, spacing after the first colon in a line of comment), tough.

Answer (score 1):

The global command could be used here. I don't have Tabular, so my version just indents all CSS blocks:

```
:%g/^.*{/+ | .,/}/->
```

The last command after `|` is the Ex-mode command to indent the block from the current position (one line below each opening brace) to line above the closing brace. Based on what you've said, I'd expect this to work, but I haven't tried it:

```
:%g/^.*{/+ | Tab /:\zs
```

Comment: That aspect of Tab is completely internal, so there isn't much hope.  But it doesn't seem like a hard script to write.  It would have to make two passes, one to find the correct column, another do the alignment.  If you're new to scripting this would be a good project.  If  you'd like me to do it, just add a bounty!  :-)